# How to get errback from interrupted response using klein?

Tags: python, twisted

[This page](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/web-in-60/interrupted.html) describes how to set an errback that fires when the connection to
the client is lost before the response is generated.

Is there a way to do something similar using klein?
Code from referenced page is below, which works with twisted.web. I would like something like:
    `request.notifyFinish().addErrback(self._responseFailed, call)`
which is code to fire an errback when request does not finish, that works with klein.

```
from twisted.web.resource import Resource
from twisted.web.server import NOT_DONE_YET
from twisted.internet import reactor

class DelayedResource(Resource):
    def _delayedRender(self, request):
        request.write("<html><body>Sorry to keep you waiting.</body></html>")
        request.finish()

    def _responseFailed(self, err, call):
        call.cancel()

    def render_GET(self, request):
       call = reactor.callLater(5, self._delayedRender, request)
       request.notifyFinish().addErrback(self._responseFailed, call)
       return NOT_DONE_YET

resource = DelayedResource()
```

Answer (score 1):

Klein handlers are passed a regular Twisted Web `Request` object.  You can use the same `notifyFinish` method on it to get interrupted response notification.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question as stated. I have found using klein, or even the vanilla twisted web example _responseFailed is not called. Request is interrupted by hitting escape, the errback is not called.